# Display an image using the path of the image

Tags: c++, xcode, image, path, system

I used this code below to pop an image for me but it's not working, so what is wrong with the view function?

When I call the app it opens:

```
void Image::view(){
string app="open /Applications/GIMP.app";
system(app.c_str());}
```

the app GIMP open successfully but when I do this to open my image using the app:

```
void Image::view()
string app="open /Applications/GIMP.app"+getID(); 
//getID contain the path of the image
system(app.c_str());}
```

This is the error message I got "
The file /Users/Eric/Desktop/Product/Green.ppm does not exist.
Program ended with exit code: 0"

Note: A friend use Xcode as me used the same second function and it worked perfectly with him

getID() would return /Users/Eric/Desktop/Product/Green.ppm

Comment: Because the path of the file is not right as said in the console ? Please copy your error message in your question and not on a web url.

Comment: I added the error message, It says that the file doesn't exist, while it does-apperntly not to Xcode- I copied the path from the file info, sou;ldm't this be the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path from getID() is correct, you are missing a space.

```
string app="open /Applications/GIMP.app " + getID();
```

Currently, it's trying to open /Applications/GIMP.appYourFile.Extension which is invalid. It needs /Applications/GIMP.app YourFile.Extension.

Comment: Even with using the space the same error, it should be from getID(). this is the  path I used  "/Users/Eric/Desktop/Proudct/Green.ppm"  do you find some errors?

Comment: Is that the exact path to your file? (Should it be /Users/Eric/Desktop/Product/Green.ppm ? -- You have product spelled wrong)

Comment: Opps haha yep I missed typed file name,, It's the correct path. I reached a solution I'll write it down.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

By editing the scheme by using custom working directory (to my product file) and changing getID() to return "Green.ppm" the name of the image it worked.

I guess I have a problem with my system in reading directory (I have faced this in my terminal earlier) and here is another problem to solved later!